# Ipad Safari - A href with target =" specific" doesn't focus tab

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

If I have the following a href in Safari on the Ipad. If I click the a href it loads a new tab. If I click it again with the tab open, it doesn't bring the already open tab into focus. I can't seem to find a work around.

```
<a href="http://Test" target="SpecificName">Click link</a>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Quick Steps:
1. Click link (tab will open)
2. Click link again (it looks like the tab refreshes, but it never gains focus)

How do I gain focus of that tab?